# how to change url scrolling up and down in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and want to change URL on page up and down like on down it should be `SomeUrl/#/page/1` and increment after specific height.

On up it should decrements at same height it increases.

Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.